# Custom android clock face, hands are too long

Tags: android

I have built a custom android analog clock with the following code

Here is my code to display the clock; I have overridden the default hour and minute hands by setting android:hand_mminute and android:hand_hour

```
  <AnalogClock
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:dial="@drawable/clockface"
    android:hand_hour="@drawable/hourhand"
    android:hand_minute="@drawable/minutehand"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Here is my hourhand drawable. The rotation tag encloses the shape to make sure the line starts at 12 and displays correctly. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out why the hour and minute hands cross each other and fill the width of the clock face. They should only be as long as half the width of the clock face (like the radius).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90"
android:toDegrees="90">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line"
 >

<size
    android:height="2dp"
    android:width="200dp" />



<stroke android:color="#080808" />

</shape>
</rotate>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: hi,Did you find any solution for this, How did you solve this ?